# Can someone who doesn't have a Google account be given editing rights on a Google Sites?

Tags: google-classic-sites, permissions

I have used Google Sites to set up a wiki and now want to allow three other people to be able to contribute to the wiki (full edit permission).

Do they all need to have a Google account and do I need to know which email they use to log in to their Google account to be able to grant them this permission?

So I go to the site's Sharing and Permissions page, there's a place where you can Add people and assign rights. The box says, "Enter names, email addresses, or groups...".

If I know my friend's email address, can I just enter `jill.smith@example.com` or do I have to contact her first to get the email she uses to log into Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [Google support page](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90594):

> Note that anyone you set as "Can view," "Can edit," or "Is owner" must have a Google Account or Google Apps Account to share your site.

So the only way you can give someone else editing rights, is to have the person sign up for a Google Account.